# Error ORA-06502: numeric or value error when call DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT.md5

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I call fucntion `DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT.md5(tmp_data)` and I found error

> Error ORA-06502: numeric or value error.

My tmp_data is NCLOB and I use **Oracle 10g**.

when I use the same data and call `DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT.md5(tmp_data)` again in **Oracle 11g** the error is gone.

Why run in Oracle 10g has error but 11g don't have error?

This is my code

```
create or replace FUNCTION GET_HASH ( INPUT_DATA NCLOB ) 
RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
HASHED_DATA   VARCHAR2 (2000);
BEGIN
  HASHED_DATA := RAWTOHEX (UTL_RAW.cast_to_raw(DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT.md5 (input_string  => INPUT_DATA) ));
  dbms_output.put_line('HASHED_DATA =' || HASHED_DATA);

  RETURN HASHED_DATA;
END GET_HASH_VALUE;
```

Comment: Use  DBMS_CRYPTO  instead of DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT. It has more powerfull functionality and could you please post full sql script?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can format source code with the [Code Sample `{}`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VYd26.png) toolbar button—I've done it for you this time.

Comment: I'm guessing. Nlcb value is too long more than 32767. And during the implicit conversion between  nclob and varcahr2 the error is raised.